# Get and set value from bindinglist<T> with coordinates c#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, bindinglist

I'm having trouble getting and setting the values of an item in a bindinglist with coordinates when the type vary.

For example, let's say I have three classes:

```
public class Client{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Debt{
    public string AccountType{ get; set; }
    public int DebtValue { get; set; }
}

public class Accounts{
    public string Owner{ get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsChekingAccount { get; set; }
}
```

and then, three bindinglists (imagine they are populated):

```
public BindingList<Client> listOne;
public BindingList<Debt> listTwo;
public BindingList<Accounts> listThree;
```

I'm trying to create an extension method that returns an Object with the value requested, or sets the value if it is provided.

```
public static Object GetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y) { /*some magic*/ }

public static Object SetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y, Object value) { /*some other magic*/ }
```

So, for instance, I need to be able to set the value of the item (2,3) in the listThree, and the value (1,1) in listTwo:

```
listThree.SetValueByCoordinates(2,3,false);
listThree.SetValueByCoordinates(1,1,"My self");
```

or get the value (1,1) and (2,2) from listOne and listTwo:

```
string result = listOne.GetValueByCoordinates(1,1).ToString();
intresult = Convert.ToInt32(listOne.GetValueByCoordinates(1,1));
```

How would you achieve such behavior? i was thinking of using reflection, but I know little to nothing about it.

please note that the methods MUST be called that way, so using something like this must be avoided

```
public static Object GetValueByCoordinates<T>(this BindingList<T> list, int x, int y) { /*some magic*/ }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain more specifically what you mean by "coordinate". It almost seems like you want to number properties in a class, and use that index as the `y` coordinate (with the `x` coordinate being the index in the list?). But the question is not at all clear about that. Also, why does the input parameter have to be `IBindingList`? Why not any implementation of `IList`? Finally, the question smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might consider explaining what the broader goal is, as this particular approach seems rickety.

Comment: The idea of the coordinate is, as you said, to use the "Y" to get the property of the object that was declared on "Y" place, and the "X" as the index of the item in the list.

Comment: Also, The input is a IBindingList because the application is written with that (i guess it's because they are used as datasources for grids).
Though is somehow an XY question, my problem is to know the type of the object used in the BindingList and getting/setting its properties without knowing the names.

Comment: @Zar There's one major issue. See the remark section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y28y51d8(v=vs.110).aspx) *"The order of the returned collection is not guaranteed to be identical between calls"*.  And read the remark section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *"The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies."*.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: I share your concern. However, it's worth pointing out that just because reflection doesn't itself guarantee an order, that doesn't mean that an order can't be imposed (e.g. sorting the properties by name). Still, it would be better to solve the bigger problem some other way.

Comment: There's no problem with sorting alphabetically the properties to ensure a constant order. Also, is not a must to use reflection, nor does it has to be a IBindingList, it can be an IList (i can modify the application); it is what i thought would be easier to use to achieve the goal of this function. @PeterDuniho this is the problem itself, this is the function i was asked to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, I am very skeptical that the approach you're asking for help with is likely to be the best or most appropriate way to address whatever the broader issue you're trying to solve is. It can be done (and without very much difficulty), but the resulting code is difficult to maintain, error-prone, and not very readable (which leads to the first two problems).

That said, there are lots of different ways to implement the specific behavior you're asking for. And even if this is not the best way to solve your current problem, the basic techniques are useful to know for other types of problems. With that in mind, here are two of the most obvious ways you might address your problem.

**Manually configure a mapping from indexes to getters and setters:**

IMHO this is the most preferable way. Not because it's elegant or easy to extend, but specifically because it's *not* either of those things. Requiring code maintainers to explicitly create the data structure elements to support each type and property that you want to handle will discourage a proliferation of this technique for other related problems, and even for the current problem. It could even encourage someone to spend a little more time thinking about the broader problem so as to find a better strategy.

This approach does have the advantage that it is reasonably performant. Because the code is generated at compile time, the only real overhead is the boxing that occurs for value types. There's some casting but for the reference types that overhead should be practically unmeasurable, and even the boxing overhead may not show up on a profile, depending on how intensively this code might be used.

This particular solution looks like this:

```
static class ManualIndexedProperty
{
    public static void SetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y, object value)
    {
        object o = list[x];

        _typeToSetter[o.GetType()][y](o, value);
    }

    public static object GetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y)
    {
        object o = list[x];

        return _typeToGetter[o.GetType()][y](o);
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>[]> _typeToGetter =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>[]>()
        {
            {
                typeof(Client),
                new Func<object, object>[]
                {
                    o => ((Client)o).Name
                }
            },

            {
                typeof(Debt),
                new Func<object, object>[]
                {
                    o => ((Debt)o).AccountType,
                    o => ((Debt)o).DebtValue,
                }
            },

            {
                typeof(Accounts),
                new Func<object, object>[]
                {
                    o => ((Accounts)o).Owner,
                    o => ((Accounts)o).AccountNumber,
                    o => ((Accounts)o).IsChekingAccount,
                }
            },
        };

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object, object>[]> _typeToSetter =
        new Dictionary<Type, Action<object, object>[]>()
        {
            {
                typeof(Client),
                new Action<object, object>[]
                {
                    (o1, o2) => ((Client)o1).Name = (string)o2
                }
            },

            {
                typeof(Debt),
                new Action<object, object>[]
                {
                    (o1, o2) => ((Debt)o1).AccountType = (string)o2,
                    (o1, o2) => ((Debt)o1).DebtValue = (int)o2,
                }
            },

            {
                typeof(Accounts),
                new Action<object, object>[]
                {
                    (o1, o2) => ((Accounts)o1).Owner = (string)o2,
                    (o1, o2) => ((Accounts)o1).AccountNumber = (int)o2,
                    (o1, o2) => ((Accounts)o1).IsChekingAccount = (bool)o2,
                }
            },
        };
}
```

Two dictionaries are declared, one each for setting and getting property values. The dictionaries map the element object's type to an array of delegate instances to perform the actual work. Each delegate instance references an anonymous method which has been hand-coded to perform the necessary operation.

One major advantage to this approach is that it is explicit and obvious what index corresponds to what property for each type.

This approach will be tedious and time-consuming to set up if you are dealing with any significant number of types and/or properties. But IMHO that's a good thing. As I noted above, hopefully the pain of this approach can help convince someone to abandon the idea of accessing the properties by index altogether. :)

If this kind of tedium is unacceptable and yet you still insist on the indexed-property-access approach, then you can in fact use reflection as an alternative…

**Use reflection to access the properties:**

This technique is more dynamic. Once implemented, it works for any type object without modification, and does not require additional work to support new types.

One major *disadvantage* is that in order to produce consistent, predictable results, it sorts the properties by name. This ensures that changes in the C# compiler and/or CLR won't break the code, but it means you can't add or remove properties from a type without updating the code that is accessing those properties by index.

In my demo usage code (see further below), I address this maintenance issue by declaring `enum` types that provide `int` values for property names. This would be a good way to help reduce the maintenance overhead if the code is actually referring to the properties with literal index values.

However, it's possible your scenario involves dynamically accessing the property values by index, e.g. in a serialization scenario or similar. In that case, you will also need to add something that can remap or otherwise deal with changes in the index values should properties be added or removed to the types.

Frankly, either way this issue of the types indexes changing is one big reason I'd strongly recommend against this indexed access to properties in the first place. But again, if you insist…

```
static class ReflectionIndexedProperty
{
    public static void SetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y, object value)
    {
        object o = list[x];

        GetProperty(o, y).SetValue(o, value);
    }

    public static object GetValueByCoordinates(this IBindingList list, int x, int y)
    {
        object o = list[x];

        return GetProperty(o, y).GetValue(o);
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetProperty(object o, int index)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties;

        if (!_typeToProperty.TryGetValue(type, out properties))
        {
            properties = type.GetProperties();
            Array.Sort(properties, (p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            _typeToProperty[type] = properties;
        }

        return properties[index];
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> _typeToProperty = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();
}
```

In this version, the code retrieves the array of `PropertyInfo` objects for a given type, sorts that array by name, retrieves the appropriate `PropertyInfo` object for the given index, and then uses that `PropertyInfo` object to set or get the property value, as appropriate.

Reflection incurs a significant run-time performance overhead. This particular implementation mitigates *some* of that overhead by caching the sorted arrays of `PropertyInfo` objects. That way, they only need to be created once, the first time the code has to handle an object of the given type.

**Demo code:**

As I mentioned, to make it easier to compare the two approaches without having to go to each method call and hand-change an integer literal used for the call, I created some simple `enum` types to represent the property indexes. I also wrote some code to initialize some lists that could be tested.

**Note:** one very important thing to point out is that in your question you were not very consistent about how you were indexing the properties. In my code example, I have chose to stick with a 0-based index (consistent with the natural indexing used in C# arrays and other collections). You can of course use a different base (e.g. 1-based indexing), but you will need to make sure you are entirely consistent throughout the code (including subtracting 1 from the passed-in index when actually indexing an array).

My demo code looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BindingList<Client> listOne = new BindingList<Client>()
        {
            new Client { Name = "ClientName1" },
            new Client { Name = "ClientName2" },
            new Client { Name = "ClientName3" },
        };

        BindingList<Debt> listTwo = new BindingList<Debt>()
        {
            new Debt { AccountType = "AccountType1", DebtValue = 29 },
            new Debt { AccountType = "AccountType2", DebtValue = 31 },
            new Debt { AccountType = "AccountType3", DebtValue = 37 },
        };

        BindingList<Accounts> listThree = new BindingList<Accounts>()
        {
            new Accounts { Owner = "Owner1", AccountNumber = 17, IsChekingAccount = false },
            new Accounts { Owner = "Owner2", AccountNumber = 19, IsChekingAccount = true },
            new Accounts { Owner = "Owner3", AccountNumber = 23, IsChekingAccount = true },
        };

        LogList(listThree);

        listThree.SetValueByCoordinates(2, (int)AccountsProperty.IsChekingAccount, false);
        listThree.SetValueByCoordinates(1, (int)AccountsProperty.Owner, "My self");

        LogList(listThree);

        string result1 = (string)listOne.GetValueByCoordinates(0, (int)ClientProperty.Name);
        int result2 = (int)listTwo.GetValueByCoordinates(1, (int)DebtProperty.DebtValue);

        LogList(listOne);
        LogList(listTwo);

        Console.WriteLine("result1: " + result1);
        Console.WriteLine("result2: " + result2);
    }

    static void LogList<T>(BindingList<T> list)
    {
        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Note that I use simple casting to convert from `object` to the specific type, both with setting property values and getting them. This is a much better approach than e.g. calling `ToString()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`; you know exactly what the type is supposed to be, and it's either an actual instance of that type (for reference types) or a boxed instance (for value types), and either way a cast does exactly what you need.

I also added `ToString()` overrides to your example classes to make it easier to see the output:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{" + Name + "}";
    }
}

public class Debt
{
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    public int DebtValue { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{" + AccountType + ", " + DebtValue + "}";
    }
}

public class Accounts
{
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsChekingAccount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{" + Owner + ", " + AccountNumber + ", " + IsChekingAccount + "}";
    }
}
```

Finally, here are the `enum` declarations used:

**Manual indexing:**

```
enum ClientProperty
{
    Name = 0
}

enum DebtProperty
{
    AccountType = 0,
    DebtValue = 1
}

enum AccountsProperty
{
    Owner = 0,
    AccountNumber = 1,
    IsChekingAccount = 2,
}
```

**Reflection/sorted by name:**

```
enum ClientProperty
{
    Name = 0
}

enum DebtProperty
{
    AccountType = 0,
    DebtValue = 1
}

enum AccountsProperty
{
    AccountNumber = 0,
    IsChekingAccount = 1,
    Owner = 2,
}
```

Of course, these could both have been the same values. That is, while you don't have control over the sort order, once the property names are given, the manual version could have declared the manually-written lambdas in sorted-by-name order so that the same indexes would have worked either way. It doesn't matter too much what you decide to do; it just has to be consistent.

**Final thoughts…**

Have I mentioned yet how strongly I would recommend against building any significant amount of code around this technique? It's not at all clear what your actual bigger-picture problem you're trying to solve is, but there are just a lot of different ways for this to go wrong, and it is likely to lead to lots of hard-to-find, time-consuming-to-fix bugs in the code.

In terms of performance, the above should not be too bad as long as you are not executing the code in a tight loop for huge numbers of objects and property values. The manual (first) example in particular should be relatively fast. It is possible to achieve the generalized design of the reflection-based approach with the minimal overhead of the manual approach by using the `Expression` type. That's a bit more complicated, but would have the advantage that you can generate expressions dynamically that wind up being effectively the compiled-code implementation of the manual approach.

Comment: I know and agree that is an ugly way to get or set values in a bindinglist, but sadly we are forced to do so for now, I'm pretty sure that in the future we'll change this. I'm using the first solution and is working pretty well so far (i had to set quite a few properties). Thank you for your help

Comment: Greta answer @Peter! I'd like to share another (perhaps a more natural) approach; constrain the extension method by the [ICustomTypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. So the getter could be `public static object GetValueByCoordinates<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int x, int y) where TSource : ICustomTypeDescriptor` and the return would then be `return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)source.ElementAt(x)).GetProperties()[y];`.